# Skyrim Character Creation Problem

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I'm playing Skyrim through Steam on the PC. 
Early last year I encountered a problem after subscribing to a lot of mods. After trying to fix it I gave up and am only just now attempting to fix it again. 
I've unsubscribed from all mods, deleted all save files, deleted all files relating to Skyrim on my computer, and reinstalled through Steam (no physical copy.) Then I verified the integrity of the files through Steam. I've had no success and would appreciate any pointers you can give me. I'm not very computer literate, but I've done quite a bit of research into this problem and am fresh out of ideas. The problem is:

At the beginning of the game when you are prompted to customize and then name your character, I am unable to proceed beyond choosing my character's race. I can scroll between the various races, but I can not choose the race and proceed to the body, the face, etc.

I am able to press R and name my character and proceed with the story. But I'm quite set on being able to choose what my character looks like beyond the preset race and gender.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Edit in response to comment: I've used mouse clicks, arrows, wasd, and probably quite a few other buttons in frustrated mashing. :) 
Ah, I have used ShowRaceMenu as well and it is also broken.

Comment: Exactly how are you trying to navigate through this menu? you have to click the arrows with your mouse pointer, arrow keys do not work (for me atleast)

Comment: It may be possible to use the `ShowRaceMenu` console command to edit your character after you run through the games intro. (However this may also be broken, as it uses the same menus)

Comment: You could try (and i say try) to use this mod http://www.nexusmods.com/skyrim/mods/29624/?tab=1&navtag=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.nexusmods.com%2Fskyrim%2Fajax%2Fmoddescription%2F%3Fid%3D29624%26preview%3D&pUp=1

Comment: If this doesn't work either, then you need to assume that its a deep software problem and not just a UI problem

Comment: ALso make sure you don't have the option to play with a controller checked on

Comment: You can [change your face after](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Surgery), so don't let your initial appearance deter you from this great game.  Also, a lot of times you just stare at the back of your character's head, if they don't have a helmet.. If they do, then you get to stare at the helmet.

Answer (score 2):

I had this issue. I found if you lower your resolution settings either in the Skyrim Launcher, Geforce experience or whatever, start the game make your character (should be working then) save then restart the game with optimized resolution settings you should be able to bypass this problem. Good luck, i hope it helps.

Comment: Hi @jAngA, welcome to Arqade. I have reset your profile picture to the default as it was a little too graphic for our site. You are more than welcome to re-change it to an image that is a little more PG-13 :-)